# Categorize list of installed applications programmatically on Android

Tags: android, application-settings

I have a function that gets the list of all the installed applications on the user's phone. Is there anyway I can sort this list based on the category of the application installed?
Example - Messenger,Whatsapp, Facebook messenger}
What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application info may contains some like this:

Packagename,
Applicationname,
Permissions, 
icons & images.

So, We can't be able to get google playstore data for that app. Google playstore have category and other that cant get as programatically.

u may try on this sdk but its unofficial API  http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6175782/4609016